Am I allowed to initialise the flask app in the setup script?
I am writing a small flask app for school. In my app I use flask-sqlalchemy and flask-login. In the application factory create_app() I create the schemas, the tables and a default admin user if they don't exist. This all work fine in development.
In production I use gunicorn to run the app. There I started to have some peculiar problem with the gunicorn workers interfering with each other. One example would be the .create_all() function of SQLAlchemy:
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1684, "Table 'pika_library'.'books' was skipped since its definition is being modified by concurrent DDL statement")

The exception only happens when the tables do not exist already and they actually need to be created, which is why it is not really a problem in development.
To solve this problem I had to get creative with try statements:
while True:
   try:
      db.create_all()
      break
   except OperationalError as exception:
      if exception.orig.args[0] == 1050 or exception.orig.args[0] == 1684:
         pass
      else:
         app.logger.warning(exception)

This works, but I do not think it is best practice.
My solution now would be to create a setup script to run .create_all(), create default users and whatever else only once and not having to catch errors of concurrent interfering workers. That script would either be in the wsgi.py file or in a on_starting() function for gunicorn.
Now to my actual question: Is it best practice i.e. am I allowed to initialise my app once in a separate setup script to have access to the application context and then to have gunicorn actually start the application?

you should create table before you run flask code - because gunicorn can run the same code in may workers/threads and this can make problem. Besides you have to create it only once so there is no reason to run it in flask and gunicorn.

Agreed, that’s why I ask if I am allowed to initialise the app once in a script to have access to the app context.

Don't initialise database in this script but create other script only for db.create_all(). And run other script (manually) only once - and later you can run flask all time without db.create_all()

I experimented a bit and that is what I ended up doing. But I would still like to know whether initialising the flask app in the setup script can be considered best practice?

I can say two things: (1) why to keep in app.py code which you have to run only once ?  It seems waste of memory. And someone could accidentally change code and run it again - and delete data in database. (2) django doesn't keep it in main code. It has special script manager.py which you can use to create database, to update structure in database when you change Model, and to set superuser (admin) in this database.
